I can't get ubuntu to load after upgrading its stuck with this message /dev/sda3: clean, I have tried most of the suggestions from previous posts
I don't think my computer (old laptop) can access the Internet, how can I check this from command screen..?
It was turned off (lid closed) by my 5 Yr old during the download of the upgrade..
I'm not at all computer savvy... My friend put ubuntu on who I no longer have contact with!

This question is similar to: "dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try this:
Power on the affected machine.
Wait until the BIOS has finished loading.
Press and hold the Shift key, which will open the GNU GRUB menu.
Select the line that starts with "Advanced Options".
Select the line that ends with "(recovery mode)"
Press Enter and the machine will start the boot process.
After a few moments, the workstation will display a menu with a number of options.
One of the options will be "Root - Super User Console". Select it and press Enter.
The root partition is mounted in read-only mode.
To mount it read/write, enter the command:
 mount -o rw,remount /

If we have /home, /boot, /tmp, or any other mount point on a separate partition, you can mount them with the command:
 mount –all

Continue running:
 dpkg --configure -a 

 apt -update 

 apt -f install 

 apt dist-upgrade 

 apt clean 

 apt autoremove 

 reboot


Hey @kyodake thanks for your response, I'm trying this now but nothings happening when I hold the shift key, it's quite an old machine could there be another way to access the GRUB menu?

@Phen: Before the boot screen appears, you must press the Shift, Esc, or other key depending on the manufacturer to access the grub boot menu.
